# Error "executing command 'ant'", Creating Project using cordova 3.3 through CLI

Tags: android, cordova

```
C:\Users\saurabh.trivedi\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q
.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^

Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.

    at C:\Users\saurabh.trivedi\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check
_reqs.js:47:27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. here is the exact solution.

Control Panel\System and Security\System\
click advanced system settings
click Environment variables
In system variables :
ANT_HOME: C:\ant
path: %ANT_HOME%\bin;

This will work..

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar error. To overcome the issue I downloaded and installed apache-ant-1.9.2 into the "C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.2\" folder and added the "C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\;" to the "Path" environment variable.

Note, that additional environment variables (ANDROID_HOME) and paths to JRE, and Android SDK are also should be set for correct Cordova CLI operation under Windows for me:

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\ADT\sdk

Path = ...<some paths for other programs>... + C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ADT\sdk\tools\
```