# error on “cordova platform add android”

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I am creating an application in phonegap and I arrived at the stage of creating an android application, I try to install from the command line, I always receive this error here is an example of error, knowing that I have installed apache ant and I set their path in the path variable

```
    C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;

     Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
    at C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:47:27
    at exithandler (child_process.js:633:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:649:5)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:787:12)
Error: C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Comment: Error Clearly says `executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.`

Comment: I also clearly say that I've already installed it and configured it in my path :|

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "executing command 'ant'", Creating Project using cordova 3.3 through CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796551/error-executing-command-ant-creating-project-using-cordova-3-3-through-cli)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor i did it but still having the problem

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :

1. Download Ant from [here](http://ant.apache.org/)
2. Uncompress the downloaded file into a directory.
3. Set environmental variables `JAVA_HOME` to your Java environment, `ANT_HOME` to the directory you uncompressed Ant to, and add `${ANT_HOME}/bin (Unix)` or `%ANT_HOME%/bin (Windows)` to your PATH.
4. Check [Setup](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#setup)

Source link : [Installing Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Look to my command line it's correctly installed `C:\Users\user>ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014`